# Difference between <% form .. and <%= form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have using rails 1.2.1 version. Generally, i have using the form tag as the following style in my all projects. 

`<% form_tag({:action => 'xxx'} etc...) do %> 
..
<% end %>`

But, when i saw the following tutorial site, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html, they guided the form tag as follows.


`<%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get") do %> 
..
<% end %>`

So, i have just try to use it. But, it shows the error. Why they are using the symbol "=" in the form tag?. What is the reason for error?.

What is the purpose of tag with equal and tag without equal.? ( <%=... and <% ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The erb tag `<%= expr %>` embeds the value of `expr` in the resultant HTML, whereas `<% expr %>` merely evaluates `expr` for its side-effects.

The semantics of `form_tag` have changed since Rails 3.  You'll want to continue using `<% form_tag %>` for pre-3.0 versions of rails.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render something at browser end then you have to use '<%=' otherwise '<%'
If you use <%=form_tag then it will render html form to the browser.